# Use vuelidate with a regex inside a rule form

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vue-component, vuelidate

I am trying to create a regular expression in Vuelidate and add it to a form with several rules.
The documentation does not say exactly how to use some custom rules, and I am using Composition API.

I have a field that I need to validate with a regex.

`'^([A-ZÑ\x26]{3,4}([0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))((-)?([A-Z\d]{3}))?$'`

The field is inside a form, so I create the rules to be used later as follows.

`// const rfc = helpers.regex('^([A-ZÑ\x26]{3,4}([0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))((-)?([A-Z\d]{3}))?$')`

I create the rules in this way

```
`const companyRules = {
  company: {
    RFC: { required, rfc },
    name: { required },
    line: { required },
    email: { required, email },
    phone: { required },
  },
  ...
};`
```

And finally I use them with the form

`const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, form);`

But it doesn't work, as it marks me as never being valid.
I tried with other simpler regex but it still never works. How should I add the rule or what should I modify in it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same issue using the `regex` helper. Even with a simple regex. I'm using the composition API + vue3 and a couple of decorators for translation.

```
// validators.ts
export const foo = withI18nMessage(
    helpers.regex("foo", /[a-z]*/)
);

// myform.vue
import { foo } from "validators"
const validators = {
    bar: {
        foo,
    }
}
```

Bar will remain invalid even with a valid value...
For now I decided to not use the regex helper and use `string.match` instead.

```
export const sshPublicKey = withI18nMessage((value: string) =>
    Boolean(value.match(/[a-z]*/))
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Vuelidates regex 'helper' isn't as helpful as your answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
const companyRules = {
  company: {
    RFC: { required, rfc: helpers.regex('^([A-ZÑ\x26]{3,4}([0-9]{2})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]))((-)?([A-Z\d]{3}))?$') },
    name: { required },
    line: { required },
    email: { required, email },
    phone: { required },
  },
  ...
};


const v$ = useVuelidate(companyRules, form);
```